# Using Multiprocessing to create a pyserial .write() , .read() processes in python3

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, pyserial

Devices used : Beaglebone_AI  and 2 STM32 nucleos connected to the Beaglebone AI using USB hub.

The idea:
The Beaglebone uses a python3 script that uses multiprocessing and pyserial to create 3 processes:

Process 1 - Request a string from STM32 #1 and adds the string to FIFO Queue

Process 2 - Function that writes all responses from STM32 #2

Process 3 - .get() from FIFO Queue go through a switch statement to process either strings from STM32 #1 or user commands.

**The Problem:**
- It seems like sometimes pyserial .write() dosnt send the user command or data.

**can Pyserial .read() and .write() at the same time ??**

This is my function process that prints everything that it receives:

````
def writeall(serial_port, q2):
    all_bytes = []
    while True:
            try:
                bytesToRead = serial_port.inWaiting()
                data = serial_port.read(bytesToRead).decode('utf-8')
                
                if not data:
                    pass
                    
                else:
                    
                    if data == '\n':
                        data = ''.join(all_bytes)
                        #Print to screen everything
                        print(data, end = '\033[K\n\n', flush=True)
                        all_bytes.clear()
                        #serial_port.reset_input_buffer()

                    else:
                        #append all the bytes that are being received
                        all_bytes.append(str(data))
                        
            except (OSError,serial.serialutil.SerialException) as e:
                print(f'Actuator Controller: {e}')  ```

**This is my serial port config:**

``` def opening_port(q2):
    global serial_port
    try:
            a =""
            for p in ports:
                #if 'COM9' in p.device: #for windows
                if "066BFF343633464257245637" in p.serial_number: #my nucleo 
                    a = p.device
                    # Port initialization 
                    serial_port = serial.Serial( 
                    port= a,
                    baudrate=9600, 
                    bytesize= serial.EIGHTBITS, 
                    parity= serial.PARITY_NONE, 
                    stopbits= serial.STOPBITS_ONE, 
                    timeout= 1)
                    
            # Discarding anything in the I/O buffer.        
            #serial_port.reset_output_buffer()
            #serial_port.reset_input_buffer()     

            return serial_port ```


**ANd this is pyserial .write() function that uses the same port as the writeall function process**


``` def write_comand(comand):
    try:
        #Reset the buffer before sending a command 
        serial_port.reset_output_buffer()
        serial_port.reset_input_buffer()

        serial_port.write(bytes(comand,'utf8'))
        # Testing wheter the Queue is getting the user commands and if we are actually sending them 
        
        if '3E12' in str(comand):
            pass
        else : 
            print(f" cmd sent {comand}\n")
                
        #time.sleep(0.005)

    except (OSError,serial.serialutil.SerialException) as e:
            print (f" There was a problem communicating with AC: {e}\n")
            print('Resetting Actuator Controller...\n')
            write_comand('B6D8\r')# reset command ```
````

Comment: do you expect us to analyze 200 lines of code for you?

Comment: sorry you are right I edited the question can you take a look please?

Comment: @0___________ could you please review the question now that I reduced it to the most important problem??

Comment: Pyserial .write() sometimes dosnt send